# elasticsearch aggregation fields with text type mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to aggregate on a field that has `type text`.

Mapping setting:

```
"Group":{"type":"text"}
```

And query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "request_id": 22
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "sets": {
            "terms": {"field": "Group.keyword"}
        }
    }
}
```

This gives empty results:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 7463,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "sets": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": []
    }
}
```

Without `.keyword` gives `illegal_argument_exception`.. `reason: ... alternatively use a keyword field instead.`.

Also, values in `Group` field are `Grp1` and `Grp2` only.

How can I aggregate sets based on these two values?

Answer (score 2):

Update mapping to:

```
"Group": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
```

After making the above change in mapping, re-index the documents and then you can use `Group.keyword`

If you would never want full text search on the values of Group field then you should keep it type as keyword.

```
"Group":{"type":"keyword"}
```

In this case you can aggregate on `Group` field itself.