# Return top fields based on nested field sums in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a total ES beginner and I wonder if what I want to do is even possible.
I have the following a `viewer` index with the following mapping:

```
"mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {"type": "text"},
            "name": {"type": "text"},
            "location": {"type": "text"},
            "viewed_videos": { //array of all the videos a viewer saw and their view counts
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {"type": "text"},
                    "name": {"type": "text"},
                    "description": {"type": "text"},
                    "times_viewed": {"type": "long"},
                },
            },
        }
    }
```

I want to figure out what are the most viewed videos by location. So I need a way to sum up the `times_viewed` for each `viewed_video` across many `viewer`s and then get the top X ones for a given location.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
You will need a three level aggregation -

- term aggregation on location field
- nested term aggregation on viewed video IDs
- sum aggregation on the times viewed

However, term aggregations cannot be performed on text fields. Please check the note in documentation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html:

> By default, you cannot run a terms aggregation on a text field. Use a keyword sub-field instead. Alternatively, you can enable fielddata on the text field to create buckets for the field’s analyzed terms. Enabling fielddata can significantly increase memory usage.

This might help as well: [elasticsearch aggregation fields with text type mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440782/elasticsearch-aggregation-fields-with-text-type-mapping)

Once the above issue is fixed, this query should work -

```
GET viewer/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "location": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "location"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "videos": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "viewed_videos"
          },
          "aggs": {
             "type": {
               "terms": {
                    "field": "viewed_videos.id"
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "count": {
                    "sum": {
                      "field": "viewed_videos.times_viewed"
                    }
                  },
                  "sorted_count": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                      "sort": [
                        { "count": { "order": "desc" } } 
                      ],
                      "size": <X> // top X results                            
                    }
                  }
                } 
              }
            }
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```